# How to update a list item with event reciever? Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, development

I have a list with 3 columns which are `Name`, `Department` and `DepartVersion`.
I have also created an list item event receiver, its invoked when an `Item is being Updated` and I have the following code:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {

            SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

            currentItem["DepartVersion"] = "The Item Was changed, it was: "  
                  + currentItem["DepartVersion"].ToString()

            currentItem.Update();

        }
    }
```

this code builds and deploys perfectly but when i try to edit and save an item it shows me the following error: `Save Conflict Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user event receiver sharepoint`

How can I fix this.

Answer (score 3):

You event receiver is done on itemUpdating .... any updates to current item should be done in ItemUpdated. Also before you call item.update() you need to call 

`this.EventFiringEnabled = false; 
item.update(); 
this.EventFiringEnabled = true;`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that when you are doing `currentItem.Update()` it is then firing another `ItemUpdating` event.

Disable event firing before doing the update, then re-enable it afterwards:

```
public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
    {

        SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

        currentItem["DepartVersion"] = "The Item Was changed, it was: "  + currentItem["DepartVersion"].ToString();

        try
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
            currentItem.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch exception
        }
        finally
        {
            this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: however it is not working!

Comment: same error occures!

Comment: Use Visual Studio to debug. Skip line by line and see where it's falling over. I have a hunch it won't be the FIRST time you do `currentItem.Update()`.

Comment: ok i have another case I have a variable in another event receiver how can I call this variable to another event receiver in a same project example i have a `string name`?